# I am working on parsing a JSON response

Tags: ios, iphone, json, swift, parsing

I am working on parsing a JSON response, I need to get data from the key FILES, but code is not working

```
 do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String : AnyObject]
        if let name = json["LIBRARY"] as? [[String : AnyObject]]{
            if let files = name["FILES"] as? [[String : AnyObject]]{
                for file in files {
                    var info = Modal()
                   info.audioUrl = file["SRC"] as? String
                   print(info.audioUrl)
                   self.modals.append(info)
                } 
            }
        }
} catch let error {
   print(error)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all in Swift 3 the standard JSON dictionary is `[String:Any]`.

Since the value for key `LIBRARY` is (correctly parsed) an array, you have to subscript the array by index

```
if let library = json["LIBRARY"] as? [[String : Any]], !library.isEmpty {
   if let files = library[0]["FILES"] as? [[String : Any]] {
```

And – as always – `.mutableContainers` is completely meaningless in Swift, omit the parameter,

Comment: thank you!!! your answer very helpful.

Comment: if in SRC are many url?

Comment: According to the JSON that's not possible, `files` can be multiple items but that covers your code.

Comment: @programmer this code is going to crash when library array will be empty. Check my answer I covered this mistake and also took care about multiple files.

Comment: @KamilHarasimowicz This code definitely does **not** crash if library array is empty.

Answer (score 2):

I think in your code `name` is an array so to get `files` instance you should replace your code with:

```
if let namesArray = json["LIBRARY"] as? [[String : AnyObject]]{
    for name in namesArray {
        if let filesArray = name["FILES"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
            for file in filesArray {
                print(file["SRC"])
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is invalid. `name` is an array. `name["FILES"]` isn't valid for an array.

Comment: @rmaddy I know that but someone edited my original post (check edition history) I restored first version of my post. Could you remove unvote or explain me what is wrong? It was not my fault. :)

Comment: That person's edit was terrible. Your rolled back answer is much better. Though your code will crash if `name` is an empty array.

Comment: @sbarow The edit you made to this answer was completely wrong. Please don't edit people's answers like that.

Comment: @rmaddy I edited answer one more time. It should not crashing.

Comment: @rmaddy I don't see what the difference is between my edit and the current edit? My bad if this was completely wrong and apologise to Kamil.

Comment: @sbarow Your edit wouldn't compile. See my first comment under this question - it applies to the answer as it existed from your edit. But that's not the point. It's fine to fix a tiny typo or to fix formatting. But please don't change the logic. Either post your own answer or post a comment expressing whatever concern you may have with the answer. Enjoy.